# How to install debug symbols when the dependency seems to be faulty?

Tags: apt, dependencies

#### Question

How do I rectify the issue to install the debug symbol package successfully?

NB: It is perfectly fine to swap the existing "main" package for another one to get it to work.

#### Description of the issue

After following the instructions [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Debug%20Symbol%20Packages) to enable APT to "see" debug packages, I wanted to install the packages `libmagick++-6.q16-8 libmagick++-6.q16-8-dbgsym`, i.e. the binaries plus debug symbols.

Alas, the attempt fails with:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libmagick++-6.q16-8-dbgsym : Depends: libmagick++-6.q16-8 (= 8:6.9.11.60+dfsg-1.3build2) but 8:6.9.11.60+dfsg-1.3ubuntu0.22.04.3 is to be installed
```

And indeed the `apt show` tells me that it depends on a package name *without* the `ubuntu*` moniker:

```
# apt show libmagick++-6.q16-8-dbgsym 2>/dev/null|grep Depends:
Depends: libmagick++-6.q16-8 (= 8:6.9.11.60+dfsg-1.3build2)
```

When doing an `apt download` I get a file `libmagick++-6.q16-8-dbgsym_8%3a6.9.11.60+dfsg-1.3build2_amd64.ddeb` which would seem to fit the bill, though. And `apt policy` appears to agree:

```
# apt policy libmagick++-6.q16-8-dbgsym
libmagick++-6.q16-8-dbgsym:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 8:6.9.11.60+dfsg-1.3build2
  Version table:
     8:6.9.11.60+dfsg-1.3build2 500
        500 http://ddebs.ubuntu.com jammy/universe amd64 Packages
```

As of today the entry from [`Packages`](http://ddebs.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy/universe/binary-amd64/Packages) for the package I *thought* I'd want to install reads:

```
Package: libmagick++-6.q16-8-dbgsym
Package-Type: ddeb
Architecture: amd64
Version: 8:6.9.11.60+dfsg-1.3build2
Auto-Built-Package: debug-symbols
Multi-Arch: same
Priority: optional
Section: debug
Source: imagemagick
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Original-Maintainer: ImageMagick Packaging Team <pkg-gmagick-im-team@lists.alioth.debian.org>
Installed-Size: 1494
Depends: libmagick++-6.q16-8 (= 8:6.9.11.60+dfsg-1.3build2)
Breaks: imagemagick-dbg (<< 8:6.9.2.10-1~)
Replaces: imagemagick-dbg (<< 8:6.9.2.10-1~)
Filename: pool/universe/i/imagemagick/libmagick++-6.q16-8-dbgsym_6.9.11.60+dfsg-1.3build2_amd64.ddeb
Size: 1320870
MD5sum: 6deff8b4e583f519169495b500cc3ab3
SHA1: 0639e18ce8834d89b1266a51797729e856d64880
SHA256: ff36d7de91b6dd478b6a55c4e78905b92a340b6004efb4feee13eb312eee9e46
SHA512: b9ffc956ae1aaf899668ecd08eed873192f4f44bf9060d0f7881923ff065a49a2ac23a7ff6703f22631fc74d1ffc09a5d38b0482a3fb36f7f9f418a2500e6095
Description: debug symbols for libmagick++-6.q16-8
Build-Ids: 583b0d85bbefc1a4bc07f249fea48ceab868673c
```

... and so points to [pool/universe/i/imagemagick/libmagick++-6.q16-8-dbgsym_6.9.11.60+dfsg-1.3build2_amd64.ddeb](http://ddebs.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/i/imagemagick/libmagick++-6.q16-8-dbgsym_6.9.11.60+dfsg-1.3build2_amd64.ddeb) which is the exact file `apt download` has downloaded (I checked).

I made sure to remove all additional APT sources (other than for [the ddeb as per the instruction](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Debug%20Symbol%20Packages)) and `apt update` to rule out interference from those sources (although it should have been visible from `apt policy` output if that were the case).

Re-reading the error message, I figured that the issue is the version of the already installed `libmagick++-6.q16-8` (which got automatically picked):

```
# apt policy libmagick++-6.q16-8
libmagick++-6.q16-8:
  Installed: 8:6.9.11.60+dfsg-1.3ubuntu0.22.04.3
  Candidate: 8:6.9.11.60+dfsg-1.3ubuntu0.22.04.3
  Version table:
 *** 8:6.9.11.60+dfsg-1.3ubuntu0.22.04.3 500
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     8:6.9.11.60+dfsg-1.3build2 500
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe amd64 Packages
```

Attempting to pin the undesired version at lower priority didn't work, however:

```
Package: libmagick++-*
Pin: version *ubuntu0.*
Pin-Priority: 100
```

---

System is an up-to-date Ubuntu 22.04.

```
# dpkg --print-architecture
amd64
```

Full contents of the `sources.list` and a single subordinate file:

```
$ grep -vP '^(#|\s*$)' /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy universe
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates universe
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security universe
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ddebs.list:deb http://ddebs.ubuntu.com jammy main restricted universe multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ddebs.list:deb http://ddebs.ubuntu.com jammy-updates main restricted universe multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ddebs.list:deb http://ddebs.ubuntu.com jammy-proposed main restricted universe multiverse
```

---

Attempting manual installation with `dpkg -i` of the downloaded `.ddeb` I get:

```
# dpkg -i libmagick++-6.q16-8-dbgsym_6.9.11.60+dfsg-1.3build2_amd64.ddeb
Selecting previously unselected package libmagick++-6.q16-8-dbgsym:amd64.
(Reading database ... 220284 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack libmagick++-6.q16-8-dbgsym_6.9.11.60+dfsg-1.3build2_amd64.ddeb ...
Unpacking libmagick++-6.q16-8-dbgsym:amd64 (8:6.9.11.60+dfsg-1.3build2) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libmagick++-6.q16-8-dbgsym:amd64:
 libmagick++-6.q16-8-dbgsym:amd64 depends on libmagick++-6.q16-8 (= 8:6.9.11.60+dfsg-1.3build2); however:
  Version of libmagick++-6.q16-8:amd64 on system is 8:6.9.11.60+dfsg-1.3ubuntu0.22.04.3.

dpkg: error processing package libmagick++-6.q16-8-dbgsym:amd64 (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libmagick++-6.q16-8-dbgsym:amd64
```

Comment: What architecture are you using?  Your details show *depends* & sources requirements from different architectures thus it appears to me that you're sources are polluted by added and incompatible architectures. Are you using *amd64 i386* OR *arm64 armhf ppc64el riscv64 s390x* as this is what has created your issues it appears to me..

Comment: @guiverc I am using both `amd64` and `i386`. The latter is required for a bunch of packages related to Wine. Could you detail which discrepancy you are referring to? I didn't notice any, even after looking at it again now ...

Comment: I picked one package from your list & contrasted packages what you provided with package expected and as you can see at https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libmagick%2B%2B-6.q16-8&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all your details match a system I feel a system with polluted sources/packages for more than one incompatible architecture (and not *amd64* & *i386* that match you'll note in the link; but as stated in prior comment

Comment: @guiverc that's a fair point. I commented out the `backports` line in `sources.list` now (but it makes no difference to `apt policy` as I had already assumed based on the respective source URLs). However, if you are right, that actually worsens the problem, because it suggests that there isn't a corresponding debug symbol package _at all_ to go with the "main" package(s) available ... at least there's no `libmagick++-6.q16-8-dbgsym` with a matching version, nor a `-dbg` package _at all_. But the "wrong" `-dbgsym` package at least has the correct arch, although not being listed :-|